# Can an android app resource be shared with another app?

Tags: android, android-sharing

Is it possible to share a particular app's resource, like a bitmap image/icon placed under res folder with another app?
This was asked in an interview, and I had no clue. Is there a concrete reason why such sharing can not happen, or if it is possible, how?

Comment: no another app does not have access to your resources

Comment: @tyczj: Actually, they do. Resources are world-readable, if you know the package name of the other app. That is how a home screen app can display your launcher icon and caption, for example.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on what is the meaning of "sharing".

App-2 cannot access resources of App-1 directly.

However, if App-1 provides an `Intent` which can return an image from its resources as intent extra data, then, it can be considered to be "shared" (as now App-2 can invoke that intent to access the resource).

Comment: And, if by "sharing" they meant `ACTION_SEND`, there is no direct way to share a resource. However, with a suitable `ContentProvider`, you can (see [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider), for example).

Answer (score 0):

No. Not at all. 
But when you want create 2 applications based on this same resources you can use android library project

Comment: Thanks for the answer. my question was mainly to know if a resource of an already installed app can be shared with other apps on the same device.